# How do I code a progress bar for Windows 7 to also update itself on the taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-7

Windows 7 has an AWESOME new feature that applications can report the progress of the current activity through the status bar. For example, when copying file(s) using Windows Explorer, a progress bar is layered on top of the application icon in the task bar and the progress is shown as it updates.

What is the API for exposing the progress bar? Is there MSDN documentation on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a good article in MSDN magazine about [the new taskbar APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx). And yes, the feature is awesome :-)

Essentially, it's all about implementing `IFileOperation`. There's a good article about using it in managed code [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090611054331/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/cc163304.aspx).

Comment: Your second link seems to have broken

Comment: I changed the link to archive.org instead.

Answer (score 48):

**For below .NET 4, or WinForms in any .NET version**

Using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core/) from Microsoft (as Keeron mentioned), it's really simple. You just need to use the `TaskbarManager`. E.g.

To start the progress:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState.Normal);
```

To update the progress:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressValue(currentValue, maxProgressValue);
```

And when when you're done, to end the progress:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState.NoProgress);
```

There is more you can do, but that should get you started and might be all you need.

**For .NET 4 and above with WPF**

You can use [System.Windows.Shell.TaskbarItemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.aspx). E.g. in the Xaml for your main window, you'll need to add:

```
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo x:Name="taskBarItemInfo" />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

Then to update the progress, you would do something like:

```
taskBarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    taskBarItemInfo.ProgressValue = i / 100.0;
    Thread.Sleep(50); // whatever the 'work' really is
}

taskBarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None;
```

Don't forget that if you're doing the 'work' on a background thread (which is probably a good idea for long running tasks), you will need to switch back to the UI thread to update the taskbar.

Comment: The Windows API CodePack link is a broken link, it is still available from nuget though  http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core/

Comment: The package linked in the answer and in the comment does not actually contained the required class. That class is in the Shell package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that Indeterminate has no effect when the "Animations in the Taskbar and Start Menu" option is disabled in System Properties > Advanced > Performance Options > Visual Effects.

Comment: It is also important to remember that .ProgressValue runs in fractions from 0 to 1

Answer (score 5):

If you plan to use other Windows 7 Taskbar features, another approach would be to use the library from Microsoft: Windows API Code Pack for .NET Framework which is no longer available at the [old link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), but can be found on [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core/).

Answer (score 1):

I've written an article about implementing the Windows 7 Taskbar progress API in C# (see: [Windows 7 Taskbar Progress Bar with C# and .NET](http://wyday.com/blog/2009/windows-7-taskbar-progress-bar-with-csharp-and-dotnet/)). The control is open source (BSD) and has example projects for C# and VB.NET.

This way you don't have to convert the C++ code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I use Telerik's RadWindow which you cannot just use `<telerik:RadWindow.TaskbarItemInfo>`. So I use this workaround for net6.0-windows WPF:

In code behind file I made a property:

```
public Lazy<TaskbarItemInfo> TaskbarItemInfo { get; set; } = new Lazy<TaskbarItemInfo>(() => 
{
   return System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo(); 
});
```

In method part of `BackgroundWorker`

```
private void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
```

I set the value of the progress:

```
TaskbarItemInfo.Value.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
TaskbarItemInfo.Value.ProgressValue = (double)progressUserState.ProgressInPercent / 100;
```

In

```
private void WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
```

I reset the state:

```
TaskbarItemInfo.Value.ProgressValue = 0;
TaskbarItemInfo.Value.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None;
```