# Information needed on how to code for Windows 7 Taskbar in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-7, .net-4.0, taskbar

What i know so far about how to code for win 7 taskbar features is that i can either use .net 4 or WinAPI code pack in .net3.5 or pinvoke.

My question is that can i code for win 7 task bar features using .net3.0 or prev and using pinvoke can i use features such as thumbnail toolbar, jumplist, overlay icon

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I code a progress bar for Windows 7 to also update itself on the taskbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146574/how-do-i-code-a-progress-bar-for-windows-7-to-also-update-itself-on-the-taskbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get hold of [the Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and try using it with a lower version of the .NET Framework? I have read a lot of the code in there and little if any of it relies on .NET 3.5 features. If you're using VS 2010 you could probably succeed in building it against 2.0 or whatever you're using no problem. The license allows you to integrate code from the library into your project, to change it, to basically treat it as your own, so you've got nothing to lose.

Comment: kate thanks for your answer, what about pinvoke can it be used to code for all features of win 7 taskbar?

Comment: P/Invoke is a technique for invoking apis (function calls) from your platform. So your question is really "are there APIs in Windows 7 for this?" and yes there are. Sasha's blog (among others) has plenty of details on them. You can even find and copy the P/Invoke declarations from the Code Pack if you are determined to do it the hard way. I am just not sure why you would.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [series of articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20120425185455/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/12/windows-7-taskbar-apis.aspx?) on the new Taskbar API by the debugging guru [Sasha Goldshtein](https://web.archive.org/web/20131104034659/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/sasha/). You should have a look at the [Overlay Icons and Progress Bars API](https://web.archive.org/web/20130601234859/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/16/windows-7-taskbar-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx).

You can download the sample code from [Windows 7 Taskbar Developer Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/) on Microsoft Code. What you're looking for is the `IMClient` sample:

> The IMClient sample demonstrates how
> taskbar overlay icons and taskbar
> progress bars can light up an
> application’s taskbar button instead
> of relying on an additional dialog or
> on an icon in the system notification
> area (tray).
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [microsoft.co.il](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/image_thumb_1DD568AF.png))</sub>

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [microsoft.co.il](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/image_thumb_70B05613.png))</sub>

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [microsoft.co.il](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/image_thumb_51C9BC68.png))</sub>

I believe this should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Sasha's articles are great and if you want to use the APIs yourself rather than in a library I recommend them. And how can I diss a sample that mentions me? But this particular sample is kind of old and I think you'd be better served by the Taskbar demo in the Code Pack.

Comment: @Kate I had those links bookmarked, didn't even realize that they were out of date... The Code Pack seems like the answer!