# How to do overlay icons on the taskbar in Windows 7 for .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7, overlay, taskbar

Microsoft's [UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) recommend that I use [overlay icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#overlay) to show when my application has information about statuses, like unread messages or connectivity.

However, I not having much luck finding a clear tutorial on how to get starting using overlay icons in my application. Can someone recommend one, or better yet, create a tutorial on their blog for betterment of mankind?

(The question title specifically mentions Windows 7, but I think it would also be useful for Vista to be included in this tutorial, as well as backwards compatibility issues with Windows XP, etc.)

**Edit**: This question was really asked for .NET 3.5 using WinForms. Here's a quick snippet of code that should work if you download the Windows API Code Pack referenced below in [ken2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182896/945456).

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar
' Add reference to Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll
' Snipped...

If TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported Then
  TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(icon, altText)
End If
```

Comment: Taskbar overlay icons simply aren't present on the Windows Vista and XP taskbars, which is why Windows 7 is specifically mentioned. The only workaround I can think of for those versions is to put a notify icon in the system tray.

Comment: Right, I figured they weren't supported. I just wasn't sure if using taskbar overlays would cause my program to not work in Vista/XP.

Comment: I also found information from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1389263/945456) (about doing a progress bar in the taskbar icon) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) that wraps all the shell programming stuff.

You'll find a [very detailed article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49268/Windows-7-New-Features-Explained-Using-NET) that'll show you how to use it.

Note that the Windows® API Code Pack doesn't work with XP (not supported), and is very limited with Vista. Overlay icons are only available on Windows 7 for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great resource!