# Can the TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue work with WinForms?

Tags: winforms, progress

I am trying to modify a file reading application so that it has the Windows 7 green progress bar in the toolbar icon. I don't seem to have any luck and was wondering what you have to do to get it to work with WinForms ?

Here's a simple version of what I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Shell; // add reference to "PresentationFramework" & "WindowsBase"

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
        }

        private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;

            for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
            {
                if (this.TaskbarItemInfo.CheckAccess() == true) // needs to be on creating thread
                {
                    this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = n / 100d;
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that I have to (somehow) hook the TaskbarItemInfo instance to the form, or maybe to a "System.Windows.Window" ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is answered in this post I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146574/how-do-i-code-a-progress-bar-for-windows-7-to-also-update-itself-on-the-taskbar. Look for the section titled: "For below .NET 4, or WinForms in .NET 4"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I code a progress bar for Windows 7 to also update itself on the taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146574/how-do-i-code-a-progress-bar-for-windows-7-to-also-update-itself-on-the-taskbar)