# Thumb button for C# Winform

Tags: .net, winforms, shell, thumbnails

I see that in WPF app, we can easily create Thumb button as in [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8), 
but I can't find anyway to make it work in Winform app. I have tried this far

```
using System.Windows.Shell;
...
TaskbarItemInfo task = new TaskbarItemInfo();
ThumbButtonInfo button = new ThumbButtonInfo();
this.Controls.Add(button); //Error, I don't know how to add the ThumbButtonInfo to my winform.
```

I have searched [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389263/4608491), and see that there is a Windows API Code Pack for Winform, but I prefer System.Windows.Shell. Yet with Windows API Code Pack, I still have no ideal how to add a thumb button to my winform.

So my question is: how can I add a simple thumb button to a C# Winform application (it's best that just using System.Windows.Shell)?

Thanks for reading.